# Gmail message details stored to spreadsheet

Tags: gmail, google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script

I would like to know if there is a way that I could have specific messages in my email to go directly in a Google spreadsheet. For example I need all email messages with subject line of "X" be stored in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a Google Script inside the spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
function save() { 
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var threads = GmailApp.search("subject:X");
 for (var t in threads)
  ss.appendRow([threads[t].getFirstMessageSubject()]);
}
```

Comment: This works, changing `subject:X` to change the X as required

Answer (score 1):

**IFTTT** looks like it can meet your needs. Specifically, this recipe: [Add receipts & orders to Receipt Spreadsheet](https://ifttt.com/recipes/90162-add-receipts-orders-to-receipt-spreadsheet). (There are also other similar recipes.)

This recipe is triggered by a new email message with particular words in the subject, and adds a row to a specific spreadsheet.

You'd just need to customize it to your specifications.